# Single function to read one, read all, or set

Tags: php

I have the below function, it is designed so I can call:

```
$object->temp('one', 1);    //add the key `one` to the temp array with value 1
$object->temp('two', 2);    //add the key `two` to the temp array with value 2
$object->temp('three', 3);  //add the key `three` to the temp array with value 3

$object->temp('three');       //returns 3
$object->temp('three', null); //removes the `three` key
$object->temp();              //returns array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2)
```

and it works well, my only gripe is that I don't like using the `$value = 'read_temp` in the definition, it feels like a hack to me.

So, is there anything wrong with that, and how can this function be optimized?

```
public function temp($key = null, $value = 'read_temp') {
    if($key === null)
        return $this->temp;

    if ($value === null){
        unset($this->temp[$key]);
    }

    elseif ($value == 'read_temp' && isset($this->temp[$key])) {
        $value = $this->temp[$key];
    } else {
        $this->temp[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

I could split this into two `setTemp` `getTemp` (or three `clearTemp` to be pedantic) functions, but I would like to be able to have just one function call to do everything.

Comment: What is you actual reasoning to not split it into different functions? It would be much more readable to future coders. Depending on your object you could even use overloading http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: more or less my reason is that, temp is a temporary storage on that instance of the object, it is a tiny, almost "bootstrap" part of the actual class, so I want to keep it as just one small interface instead of 2/3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
public function temp($key = null , $value = null) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if( count($args) === 2 ) {
        $this->temp[$key] = $value;
    } elseif( count($args) === 1 ) {
        return @$this->temp[$key];
    } else {
        return $this->temp;
    }
}
```

`func_get_args()` will return an array of the arguments that were actually passed - i.e. excluding default values. So if no arguments were passed, return the array; if there's 1 argument (the key), return the corresponding value; and if there are 2 arguments, set the key/value pair.

I'm using the warning-suppression `@` instead of explicitly checking `isset()`. Again, the end result is the same; if you check with `isset()` and don't (explicitly) return anything for missing keys, the function still returns NULL. If you simply return `$this->temp[$key]`with no checking, but suppress the "undefined index" warning that might occur, you also get NULL.

I've also skipped the `unset()` call, since calling `$obj->tmp("key", null)` does pretty much the same thing. If you request a value that hasn't been set, you get NULL. If you set that value to NULL, you get NULL. If you were to unset the value, you'd also get NULL.
But if you want to keep the unset, you can just check `$value === null` in the first branch:

```
if( count($args) === 2 ) {
    if( $value === null ) {
        unset($this->temp[$key]);
    } else {
        $this->temp[$key] = $value;
    }
} // ...
```

If you skip the `unset()` part, it'll obviously keep the array keys around, so you won't know for sure if a key whose value is NULL was "deleted", or if it was explicitly set to NULL on purpose.
On the other hand, if you `unset()` when the passed value is NULL, you won't be able to set a value to NULL on purpose.

The simplest solution is to not use `unset` in the `temp()` function, but instead add an extra `unset_temp_value($key)` function that does the unset. Then you can use that to explicitly remove all traces of a key/value pair, while still being able to store NULLs "on purpose" using `temp($key, null)`.

---

As mseancole points out below, a `switch` statement could be used too

```
public function temp($key = null, $value = null) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  switch( count($args) ) {
    case 2:
      return $this->temp[$key] = $value;
    case 1:
      return @$this->temp[$key];
    default:
      return $this->temp;
  }
}
```

Only difference is that this returns the value that's set in the first case (just because it's more compact then `break`ing)

And just for fun, here's the same thing again in Unreadable Mode™

```
public function temp($key = null, $value = null) {
  $args = count(func_get_args());
  return ($args==2?($this->temp[$key]=$value):($args==1?@$this->temp[$key]:$this->tmp));
}
```

Comment: Cheers, just what I was looking for, but; I loathe the silence operator! so much infact that I have this set on my dev server; `ini_set('scream.enabled', true);` so I shall be using isset ;)

Comment: @Hailwood Heh, fair enough :)

Comment: @Hailwood: Just a couple of things to add to Flambino's post. **1** Why are your statements inconsistent? You are using braceless and braced code interchangeably. I honestly don't think braceless should be used at all, being as how PHP does not completely support support it, but you should at the very least be consistent. **2** A switch statement might be more appropriate in Flambino's example.

Comment: @mseancole Good point regarding `switch`, I'll add it to my answer

Comment: (Warning: annoying literalness incoming.) @mseancole I understand what you mean, and agree with your sentiments, but "PHP does not completely support [braceless syntax]" is not true.  PHP supports it perfectly.  Its behavior is well defined, yatta yatta.  Ease of misuse and lack of support are not the same thing.

Comment: @Corbin: If it fully supported braceless syntax we would not have to add braces after one line. It *is* inherently required. The half-assed version that PHP has implemented is just wrong and, imho, promotes bad habits. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should, especially if it completely deviates from everything else. Sorry for the mini-rant, I just find this feature offensive. If PHP decides to fully implement pure braceless syntax, I will revisit this opinion, in the mean time, if you want to code this way, Python and Ruby are good alternatives. Sorry that sounds harsh.

Comment: @mseancole +1 for stressing consistency; Corbin +1 for pointing out that PHP's behavior _is_ well-defined (just ill-conceived); mseancole +1 for generally ranting on PHP. I may have answered the question, but, man, I'm glad my PHP days are behind me. (Disclaimer: Subjective opinion.)

Comment: @mseancole The problem isn't PHP; it's your understanding of it.  Look at any brace based language, and it's the same.  The only reason Python is that way is because it is whitespace block-based.  PHP's treatment of a lack of braces is just like any other brace-block-based language that has been influenced by C (C/C++/Java/C#/JavaScript/etc).  (Disclaimer: Am not familiar with how braces work in Ruby, so maybe it does do something more logical.  Also, "influenced by C" being directly related to braces is debatable, but hopefully the point got across.)

Comment: @mseancole And for what it's worth, I'm a very strong advocate of always using braces.  I don't think I've ever written an if statement without braces.  It just irks the pedantic side of me to see PHP's handling called "incomplete" when it's not.